# Network problems with Ubuntu on VMware

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, vmware-player

I'm running Ubuntu 10.04 inside VMware Player running under Windows Vista and I can't connect to the internet or the host computer from the Ubuntu.

I have set all the VMware services to “manual” (like VMware DHCP Service), but starting them manually doesn't help.

In VMware, the network seems to work (there is a green dot beside the network icon) and I have tried both Bridged and NAT settings.

`ifconfig` doesn't show the `eth1` interface, unless I give it as a parameter (or use `-a`). I think this means that Ubuntu thinks that the network isn't connected at all.

How do I fix this?

```
ifconvadmin@ubu1004:~$ ifconfig
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:56 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:56 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:4192 (4.1 KB)  TX bytes:4192 (4.1 KB)

vadmin@ubu1004:~$ ifconfig eth1
eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0c:29:2d:a0:6f  
          BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:18 Base address:0x2000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hah, just by running `sudo dhclient` I got an IP address and the network is working.